# Find items that can be deleted, updated or added by start/end period

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find items that can be deleted, updated or added by passing `updatedItems` into a method, when there is an updated item with a start/end value the same (no overlaps), then the existing item will be removed and re-added with the updated start/end value.

```
const existingItems = [
    {
        id: '111',
        start: 0,
        end: 10,
        cost: 100
    },
    {
        id: '222',
        start: 20,
        end: 30,
        cost: 200
    },
];

const updatedItems = [
    {
        start: 0,
        end: 9,
        cost: 42
    },
    {
        id: '222',
        start: 20,
        end: 30,
        cost: 999 
    }
];

// expected result
const items = {
  deleted: [
    {
        id: '111',
        start: 0,
        end: 10,
        cost: 100
    }
  ],
  added: [
    {
        start: 0,
        end: 9,
        cost: 42
    },
  ],
  updated: [
    {
        id: '222',
        start: 20,
        end: 30,
        cost: 999 
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Tangent to the question: Your result data structure should also probably include a "not modified" group.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good point!

Answer (score 0):

There are many array functions available in JavaScript and so there are a lot of ways you can solve this. Ultimately it comes down to being able to iterate through both of your original objects and match up values to determine if something exists or not.

This certainly isn't the cleanest solution, but it produces the result you asked for given the input provided. Even if this is not exactly what you need, it should help point you in the right direction so you can learn.

```js
const existingItems = [
    {
        id: '111',
        start: 0,
        end: 10,
        cost: 100
    },
    {
        id: '222',
        start: 20,
        end: 30,
        cost: 200
    },
];

const updatedItems = [
    {
        start: 0,
        end: 9,
        cost: 42
    },
    {
        id: '222',
        start: 20,
        end: 30,
        cost: 999 
    }
];

function _Merge(existing, updated) {
    let newObj = {
        deleted: [],
        added: [],
        updated: []
    };
    existingItems.forEach(item => {
        if(updatedItems.filter(i => i["id"] == item["id"]).length > 0) {
            newObj.updated = [...newObj.updated, item];
        } else {
            newObj.deleted = [...newObj.deleted, item];
        }
    });
    updatedItems.forEach(item => {
        if(existingItems.filter(i => i["id"] == item["id"]).length <= 0) {
            newObj.added = [...newObj.added, item];
        }
    });
    return newObj;
}

console.log(_Merge(existingItems, updatedItems));
```

This essentially takes the existing and updated items arrays and uses `forEach()` to loop and check which of the existing items needs to be updated or deleted. Then lastly it loops through the updated items array also using `forEach()` to determine which items need to be added.

In both cases it uses the `filter()` method to compare the current item's id to an array to see if there are any records that match.